# Windows - Virtually consolidating files from several directories into a single path

Tags: windows, command-line, directory

I have been searching for this for a while but no success yet. Not sure if I'm using the right terms...

I'm trying to programmatically automatize the use of an API (from a software called Pix4D) to which I need to pass a directory path as one of the parameters. This directory is supposed to contain all files that will be processed by the aforementioned API.

The problem is that the API only accepts a single path, while my business process will always organise the input files into several input folders (I tried, but I cannot change this).

I'm trying to find a way to create an extra folder that would contain some sort of reference to all the files organised in those input folders. Thus, when one opens that "virtual folder" path, he would see all files together. This would potentially allow me to use the path for the new folder as the input for the API.

So, suppose I have these files I want the API to process:

```
C:\proc\20170101\f1.jpg
C:\proc\20170101\f2.jpg
C:\proc\20170201\f1.jpg
C:\proc\20170201\f2.jpg
C:\proc\20170301\f1.jpg
C:\proc\20170301\f2.jpg
```

I would need a single path to a directory that virtually contains all those 6 jpg files.

Some constraints:

- We don't want to duplicate files
- The virtual path needs to be created via command line
- It should work on a Windows machine
- Yes, there might be files with same names in the input folders. We can work around this, if necessary
- Open source/free solutions would be better

Any help is highly appreciated. Same goes to any different approach to the problem.

Thanks

Comment: For Windows Vista and later, you can create a directory with symbolic links to the target files. The current user needs to have the privilege to create symbolic links, i.e. either the current user is a standard user explicitly granted this privilege or an elevated administrator.

Comment: Hi @eryksun, thanks for your message. This was my first try and unfortunately it didn't work. Pix4D is not able to "translate" the symbolic links, so it sees nothing in the consolidated directory if we use this approach.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Did you actually create Windows shell shortcuts instead of filesystem symbolic/hard links? Filesystem links can be created in CMD using its `mklink` command. A shell shortcut is a .LNK file for use in the high-level Windows shell APIs, which is nothing like a real filesystem link.

Comment: Hi @eryksun. Yes, I understand the difference between a regular .lnk shorcut and a .symlink reference (created with the mklink command). However, in my particular scenario, none of these seem to work. I have tested both already. It seems that Pix4D has some kind of filter for the input files that make it only consider files with .jpg or .tif... all the links I create with mklink are simply ignored. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try hard links created via `mklink /h`. But it's very weird that symbolic links to the individual .jpg or .tif files (keeping the file extensions, and the same names where possible) would fail. The code would need to be written to either always open reparse points directly instead of letting the OS parse the final path, which would be insane unless there's a very specific and good reason to do so, or (and this one is extremely insane) to open the files, get their final path, and ignore every file that's not really in the target directory.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for not giving up :-). Well, if I create hard links, the API can indeed read the jpg files. However, I'm afraid that the hard links are similar to a copy of the original files, as they show files sizes bigger than 0Kb. To confirm this, I have permanently deleted the original jpg file and its corresponding hard link still works. As for creating symbolic links keeping file extensions, it doesn't work... the extension I inform in the command line is always ignored, resulting in a file name with the extension .symlink.

Comment: A hard link is an additional link for a file within the filesystem. It's not a copy. A hard link is limited to its own filesystem (i.e. only files on the same drive). IIRC, NTFS supports about a thousand hard links per file. For a symbolic link, the filesystem instead stores a reparse point record that has a substitute path, which can be to any local or remote filesystem (if policy allows it). It's transparent to applications unless they specifically open the reparse point or resolve the final path. CMD displays symbolic links as "<SYMLINK>" or "<SYMLINKD>" for a directory link.

Comment: `mklink` should be an internal command of the CMD shell. Thus `where mklink` should find nothing. If it does, and you're not actually using CMD, then you may be using the wrong `mklink` command. Creating ".symlink" files isn't something I recall seeing. You should be able to create a symlink in a "common" directory with a command such as `mklink "C:\proc\common\f1.jpg" "C:\proc\20170101\f1.jpg"`.